# Canonical and alternate URLs of a docusaurus website with 2 locales

Tags: internationalization, seo, docusaurus

I have a website made with Docusaurus. Initially it was in English, then I added Chinese version for many pages with `i18`. So a page like `https://www.mywebsite.com/docs/a-page` displays in English and `https://www.mywebsite.com/zh-CN/docs/a-page` displays well contents in Chinese. In `docusaurus.config.js`, at the moment, we have

```
i18n: {
    defaultLocale: 'en',
    locales: ['en', 'zh-CN'],  // Add 'zh-CN' here
    localeConfigs: {
      en: {
        label: 'English',
        htmlLang: 'en-GB',
      },
      'zh-CN': {   // Add this section for Simplified Chinese
        label: '简体中文',
        htmlLang: 'zh-Hans',
      },
    },
```

When I inspect a webpage `https://www.mywebsite.com/docs/a-page` (in english), I can see in its html

```
<link data-rh="true" rel="canonical" href="https://www.mywebsite.com/docs/a-page">
<link data-rh="true" rel="alternate" href="https://www.mywebsite.com/docs/a-page" hreflang="en-GB">
<link data-rh="true" rel="alternate" href="https://www.mywebsite.com/zh-CN/docs/a-page" hreflang="zh-Hans">
<link data-rh="true" rel="alternate" href="https://www.mywebsite.com/docs/a-page" hreflang="x-default">
```

Actually, there is only one English version of our website and it's not specifically tailored to any English-speaking region. So my questions are:

- In terms of SEO, is the current setting of `canonical` and `alternate` for english and chinese versions optimal?
- Is `hreflang="en-GB"` really necessary?

Comment: Looks good to me. Consider using hreflang="en" instead of en-GB unless your content is tailored for a specific English-speaking region.